# Title: Angular - Page not loading data after successful user add (Server Error 200)

Tags: typescript, frontend, backend, ng-bootstrap, http-status-code-200

I am working on an Angular application where I have implemented a user registration feature using a modal dialog. The user registration process appears to work correctly, and the server returns a "Server Error 200" response after successful user addition. However, the page is not loading the updated data automatically after the user is added.

Expected Behavior:
I expect the page to automatically load the updated user data from the server and display it in the table immediately after the user is added through the modal dialog.

Current Behavior:
After adding a new user through the modal dialog, the server returns a "Server Error 200" response, but the page does not automatically load the updated data. I have to manually refresh the page to see the newly added user.

I have tried manually refreshing the page after adding a user, and the user data is updated correctly in the table. However, I want the page to automatically load the updated data without requiring a manual refresh.

Can someone please help me identify the issue and suggest how to achieve the automatic page update after adding a user?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: createUserFormModal():void {
   const modalRef= this.modalService.open(CreateUserFormComponent, {
      size: 'lg',
      backdrop: 'static',
      
    });
    modalRef.result.then(
      (user: any) => {
        if (user) {
          // If the user is not null, it means the user was added successfully.
          // Emit the added user data to the parent component.
          this.userAdded.emit(user);
        }
      },
    );
  } code for user button component.

Comment: <div class="card">
  <app-create-user-button (userAdded)="onUserAdded($event)"></app-create-user-button>
  <aq-table [data]="userData" [headers]="tableHeader" [title]="title">
  </aq-table>
</div> code for listcomponent.html

Comment: load(): void {
    this.loadFromBackendWithRouteInformations().subscribe({
      next: (res: HttpArrayRespnseType) => {
        this.onResponseSuccess(res);
      },
    });
  }
  
  
  onUserAdded(user: any): void {
    // This function will be called when the userAdded event is emitted from the CreateUserFormModalComponent.
    // Add the user data to the list.
    this.userData.push(user);
    //this.load();
    
  }
  refreshPage(): void {
    this.locationService.refresh(); // Call the refresh method to refresh the page.
  }list component.ts